# jQuery code not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am a novice in jQuery, and am trying to create [this page](http://valogiannis.com/stackoverflow/coupon/). In all browsers I tested, when I click the red button a coupon code appears, except for IE. Why does this happen? And how can I fix it?

I hate this browser, really...

Javascript:

```
$(".coupon_button").live('click', function (event) { 
    $(".coupon_button").remove().fadeOut('slow');
    $(".coupon_main").after($("<div class='coupon_code'>code:newhgcoupon</div>").fadeIn());
    //$(".coupon_main").after().fadeIn('slow').html("<div class='code'>code:newhgcoupon</div>");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="module">
  <div class="coupon_title">Pay <span class="yellow">1 Cent</span> your First Month</div>
  <div class="coupon_main">To help save you some time, we created a link that takes you directly to the easily missed area on the official Medifast site that lists all of their latest specials and discounts.</div>
  <div class="coupon_button"><img src="button.png" /></div>
  <div class="coupon_footer">Expiration: 11-30-2010</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why downvotes? :O and without reasoning..is something wrong with the question?

Comment: I think it was because you didn't post any code and you didn't explain what you did. I voted you up :)

Comment: @Sotiris well I did not downvote, but perhaps people were concerned about the wording of the title. I think it's really a wasted opportunity to downvote without explaining why however.

Comment: Also it would help if you would say which version of IE is causing you problems.

Comment: @Pointy I have the problem with ie 7,8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script is not executing in IE. To fix it, just change the script type to `text/javascript`.

IE does not recognize the `application/javascript` type as being a script at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing your document.ready function. Add this line right above the first line of your script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```